# Optaplanner benchmarking with Quarkus

Tags: benchmarking, quarkus, optaplanner

I want to do the advanced benchmarking with Quarkus Optaplanner app. What is the best way to implement and run it?

When going through "old" examples for Optaplanner they all have benchmarking implemented (in this [video](https://youtu.be/Oq6kAuO_S5g?t=4909), there is a presentation about Optaplanner with Quarkus but benchmarking is shown with older examples). I built my optimization solver with Quarkus and I'm wondering how to implement benchmarking here. My input data is written in a JSON file and I would like to try different solver configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is missing feature, we're working on it, so you can just drop a benchmarkConfig.xml file in src/test/resources probably, without any entityClass etc information - or even without a config xml file at all - and just works.

- [Jira ticket](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2341)
- [Pull request](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/1249)

It will land in 8.5 or 8.6 I believe.

**Workaround**

Meanwhile, this works:

```
// This needs to be in src/main/java, because src/test/java doesn't work
// TODO move this to src/test/java after https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2341
@QuarkusMain(name = "benchmark")
public class VaccinationScheduleBenchmark implements QuarkusApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quarkus.run(VaccinationScheduleBenchmark.class, args);
    }

    @Inject
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) {
        generateDemoFile(5, 25, 0.0);
        generateDemoFile(10, 50, 0.0);
        generateDemoFile(10, 50, 0.3);
        generateDemoFile(25, 500, 0.0);
        generateDemoFile(50, 2000, 0.0);
        generateDemoFile(50, 2000, 0.3);
        // The solverBenchmarkConfig.xml explicitly mentions the entityClass, etc :(
        PlannerBenchmarkFactory benchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource("solverBenchmarkConfig.xml");
        benchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark()
                .benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser();
        return 0;
    }

    private void generateDemoFile(int vaccinationCenterCount, int totalBoothCount, double pinnedAppointmentRatio) {
        File file = new File("local/input/" + vaccinationCenterCount + "vc-" + totalBoothCount + "booths"
                + (pinnedAppointmentRatio > 0.0 ? "-" + pinnedAppointmentRatio + "pinned" : "") + ".json");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            DemoDataGenerator demoDataGenerator = new DemoDataGenerator(33.40, 34.10, -84.90, -83.90);
            VaccinationSchedule schedule = demoDataGenerator.generate(vaccinationCenterCount, totalBoothCount, pinnedAppointmentRatio);
            try {
                objectMapper.writeValue(file, schedule);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed writing file (" + file + ").", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, it's not included in 8.5 :(
I'm not familiar enough with Optaplanner yet to figure out how to use/implement your answer. Which classes do I need to make this work +how do I run it?

Comment: I have this file that you proposed and `solverBenchmarkConfig.xml` both directly in `src/main/java`. I get this error: The benchmarkConfigResource does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader (QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Runtime ClassLoader).
What can I do?